# Can anyone tell me why the value is not returned?

Tags: javascript

This is a simple javascript function, but somehow I can't figure out why the expected value is not returned. When I use console.log() within the function it returns expected value but not when I am using return.

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
    contacts.forEach((el) => {
        if (el.firstName.toLowerCase() === firstName.toLowerCase()) {
            if (el.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                console.log(el[prop]); //this prints expected value
                return el[prop] //why it's not returning any value?
            }
        }
    })
}

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes")
```

Comment: return is breaking your forEach... you should store that value then return to break the foreach, and then return the stored value OUTSIDE of the foreach

Comment: it's returning from the `forEach` callback. You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead.

Comment: You're returning a value from an anonymous function to the internal iterator of the `forEach()` method.  What do you think would be a good thing for it to do with all these return values while it's iterating?

Comment: @Crocsx `return` doesn't break forEach

Comment: @Crocsx no `return` is exiting the function, which is equivalent to exiting the current iteration. And `forEach` is simply the wrong tool here; and the "solution" you're proposing is using a crutch, at best. imo. the right tool here would be `.filter().map()`

Comment: If you really want to break the loop that is executed by the `forEach` function in the background, the only (very ugly) solution I know of is to put the `forEach` call in a `try...catch` block and throw an exception from within the function you pass to `forEach`... But I personally would definitely prefer alternative solutions, like using the `find` function instead, as @adiga did in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use forEach then you need to create an empty array and push the values when the condition is met (snippet below):

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
    const result = [];
    contacts.forEach((el) => {
        if (el.firstName.toLowerCase() === firstName.toLowerCase()) {
            if (el.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                result.push(el[prop])
            }
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

Explanation from MDN:

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() **it always returns the value undefined** and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

Answer (score 4):

You are only returning from the callback of `forEach`. It doesn't do much. You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. This gets the first item in the array that satisfies the provided condition in the callback.

```js
var contacts=[{"firstName":"Harry","lastName":"Potter","number":"0994372684","likes":["Hogwarts","Magic","Hagrid"]},{"firstName":"Sherlock","lastName":"Holmes","number":"0487345643","likes":["Intriguing Cases","Violin"]}]

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
    const found = contacts.find(el => el.firstName.toLowerCase() === firstName.toLowerCase()) || {}
    return found[prop]
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"))
```

Comment: imo. a `firstName` is unlikely to be unique. I'd go with `.filter(...).map(...)`

Comment: @Thomas I have added `|| {}` to `find`. Since OP is returning from `forEach` I assumed they wanted to break when a match is found.

Comment: @adiga could you explain why forEach wouldn't return the value? How should I understand it rather than memorize it.

Comment: @user2734550—because [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) is specified to return *undefined*, so that's what it does. You can't break out of *forEach*, it will process every element that exists in the range of 0 to length when it's called.

Comment: @user2734550 The `forEach` function takes a function as an argument... In your case it is an arrow function: `(el) => { ... }` That function is executed for each element in the array. If you `return` from that function, it has no effect on the `forEach` execution... You only "prematurely" break the handling for the current element it is processing. The `forEach` function itself returns `undefined`, as @RobG already commented.